# Что значит '\\$&amp;' в регулярке а точнее сами буквы amp?

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

```
var rule = new RegExp(name.replace(/[-[\]{}()*+?.,\\^$|#\s]/g, '\\$&amp;'), 'i');
```

Comment: Вот тут еще можно ознакомиться: [What is &amp used for](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9084259/5275890), а ответ уже у вас есть.

Answer (score 1):

[`&amp`](http://htmlhelp.com/tools/validator/problems.html#amp) - это HTML код для [амперсанда](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4) `&`.

Comment: Я так понял он не обязателен? Без него тоже работает.

Comment: @SergeLugo там, вероятно, не спроста именно html код используется.

Comment: @Serge такие штуки обычно просто так не пишутся, ибо с первого взгляда даже не понятно зачем это все, нужен какой-то конкретный кейс в котором становится понятно что за `name` и как дальше используется этот `rule`